# unable to retrieve shared preference value android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to retrieve the value from `SharedPreferences`.

```
String token = c.getString(TAG_TOKEN);
shared_preferences_editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();

shared_preferences_editor.putString("apptoken",token);
shared_preferences_editor.commit(); 

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String name = preferences.getString("apptoken","");
Log.d("apptoken",name);
```

Logcat:

```
10-18 20:50:23.730: D/apptoken(1274): android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@411e3d8
```

Can someone please show me how to get the value from the `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: please also share code how you are saving values in SharedPreferences to get more help

Comment: Where's the code where you put the string in SharedPreferences?

Comment: Did you give a name for your shared preferences file?

Comment: You mean the 'name' variable is null after calling getString? or getApplicationContext is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save and retrieve value from SharedPreference using the following way.

To write your information

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor   editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("apptoken", "your value of apptoken");
editor.commit();
```

To read above information

```
SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String token = prfs.getString("apptoken", "");
```

Hope it helps.